# How to use custom scoring function in GridSearchCV, TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, parameters

I have code below to find model with least avg_expected_loss by GridSearchCV,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit
from sklearn.base import clone
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

folds = 0 * np.ones(len(X_train_knn))
kf_train = []
kf_test = []
for i, (train_ind, test_ind) in enumerate(KFold(10, shuffle=True).split(np.arange(len(X_train_knn)))):
    kf_train.append(train_ind)
    kf_test.append(test_ind)
    folds[test_ind] = i
ps = PredefinedSplit(folds)
def custom_iterator(ps=ps):
    for train_index, test_index in ps.split():
        yield train_index, test_index
iterator_cv = custom_iterator()
iterator_scoring = custom_iterator()

def custom_loss_func(y_true, y_pred, estimator=estimator):
    cv_index= next(iterator_scoring)
    for train_index, test_index in cv_index:
        X_train_fold, X_test_fold = X_train_knn[train_index], X_train_knn[test_index]
        y_train_fold, y_test_fold = Y_train_ar[train_index], Y_train_ar[test_index]
    avg_expected_loss, avg_bias, avg_var = bias_variance_decomp(
    estimator, X_train_fold, y_train_fold, X_test_fold, y_test_fold, 
    loss='mse',
    random_seed=0)
    return avg_expected_loss
score = make_scorer(custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False)

estimator = KNeighborsRegressor()
param_grid = dict(n_neighbors=np.arange(1,2,1),weights= ['uniform', 'distance'],p= np.arange(1,2,1))
scoring_metrics ={'neg_root_mean_squared_error':'neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'r2':'r2','score_func': score}
# defining parameter range

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, cv=ps, scoring=scoring_metrics, refit='score_func', verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search=grid.fit(X_train_knn, Y_train_ar)
```

and I got this error traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\sliang017\.conda\envs\proj_logp\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\queues.py", line 159, in _feed
        obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
      File "C:\Users\sliang017\.conda\envs\proj_logp\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 215, in dumps
        dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol)
      File "C:\Users\sliang017\.conda\envs\proj_logp\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 208, in dump
        _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj)
      File "C:\Users\sliang017\.conda\envs\proj_logp\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 632, in dump
        return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object
```

Comment: It looks like joblib (which is used to parallelize the search) doesn't like the custom iterators.  I'm not very familiar with that, but do you really need the custom iterators?

Comment: custom iterators is needed to get [X_train_fold, y_train_fold, X_test_fold, y_test_fold] for custom_loss_func. any other way can I do it?